# How to pick up some random elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, random

In `Hnode` function I want to randomly choose 40 elements from the output of `SNode` function that contains 50 elements. But i got this error in `SNode` function:

```
'int[int]' for array subscript
```

I invoked `SNode` function in `Hnode` and I want to use the output of that function.

```
int HNode::database(int chunk_var)
{
    SNode::database(chunk_var);
    size=40;
    chunk_var = chunk_var[ rand() % size ]; // Here i got error
    return chunk_var ;
}
```

`Snode` was supposed to make an array with 50 elements:

```
int  SNode::database(int chunk_var)
{
    int array[50];
    srand ( time(0) );
    for(int j = 0; j<50 ;j++)
    {
        int myrand = rand() % 2 ;
        myrand = myrand & 0x3ff;
        array[j]= myrand;
        chunk_var = array[j];
    }
    return chunk_var;
}
```

How can i get ride of this error?

Comment: How can you index a normal integer `chunk_var` by the way?

Comment: This question seems very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559933/error-invalid-types-intint-for-array-subscript

Comment: @EricZ is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: The function in `SNode` doesn't output anything, but it returns an `int`, which you ignore. ( It also takes an `int` as a parameter for no reason at all).

Comment: @molbdnilo why do you think it returns anything? it was supposed to make an array. how can i change it to do that ?

Comment: @nazari `return chunk_var;` is kind of a clue that it returns something, as is the word "int" that signifies the return type.

Comment: @molbdnilo in that function chunk_var finally is an array. isn't it ? it supposed to return this array

Comment: @nazari `int chunk_var` doesn't declare an array. I would recommend that you read some more in your fine book.

Answer (score 0):

```
int HNode::database(int chunk_var)
```

Here chunk_var is an Integer. You can not access an index of an int. If you want to access it by index, chunk_var needs to be an array of Integer.

Ex.

```
int chunk_var_arr[] = {1,2,3};
HNode::database(chunk_var_arr) //function call
int HNode::database(int* chunk_var) //function declaration
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're trying to do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> SNode::database(int chunk_var)
{
    srand ( time(0) );      // do this atop main() instead!

    std::vector<int> result;

    for (int j = 0; j < chunk_var; j++)
    {
        int myrand = rand() % 2 ;
        myrand = myrand & 0x3ff;   // useless, after % it's 0 or 1 anyway
        result.push_back(myrand); 
    }
    return result;
}

int HNode::database(int chunk_var)
{
    std::vector<int> a = SNode::database(chunk_var);
    return a[ rand() % chunk_var ]; 
}
```

You're clearly way out of your depth though, and should learn to write simple standalone functions using `std::vector<>`, function parameters, `for` loops etc. before trying to write class member functions.

Comment: Thank you alot, But i wanted to fix the size of array in SNode to 50 and i wanted to pick up 40 elements out of that array in Hnode.